# vbhtml, vshtml doesn't show the correct answer for DateTime.Now.DayOfYear?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET Razor syntax using WebMatrix DateTime.DayOfYear gives 98 instead of 2016 in both vbhtml and vshtml ? what could be the problem ?

Comment: It is the 98th day of the year. Read the docs. You're looking for the Year property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now.Year` to get Year